# References to URLs returned by Apex ConnectApi in Salesforce1 mobile

Tags: salesforce1-app, chatter, chatter-file, connect-api

I have a VF page that I am using as an inline page on the Opportunity detail page layout.  It retrieves and displays files (FeedItems with [ConnectApi.ContentCapability](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_connectapi_output_content_capability.htm#apex_connectapi_output_content_capability)) from Chatter feeds on records related to the Opportunity.  After making the page available for mobile, it will display within the Salesforce1 mobile app.  However, there are two URLs returned with the ContentCapability class that wraps the Chatter File, `downloadUrl` and `renditionUrl`, that apparently don't work within the mobile container.  The following VF, where `file` is a reference to an instance of `ConnectApi.ContentCapability` renders fine on the desktop (and in /one/one.app, incidentally), but the image does not display in the mobile app, nor does the the download link work.  The title attribute works just fine.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
    <a href="{!file.downloadUrl}" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{!file.renditionUrl}" />
    </a>
    <div class="captionContainer">
        <h6>{!file.title}</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to "convert" these URLs to something that SF1 would understand...or do I need to use the Chatter REST API or some other method to fetch these URLs when the page is running in the mobile context?

The downloadUrl looks like

https://c.na17.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068o0000000wrG3?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER

and the renditionUrl looks like

https://c.na17.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=068o0000000wrj0&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=05To00000009kkc

Thanks,

Artie

Comment: does the answer provided here address your issue, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51867/can-we-open-files-attachments-in-salesforce1-without-enabling-chatter?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, @anmrk, but no.  I've got Chatter enabled and can see Salesforce Files in the regular Feed in SF1.  My issue is how to make reference to the URLs returned by the Connect API in a VF page embedded in a page layout in SF1.

Comment: Artie, I've let the Salesforce dev teams know about this issue and they're researching it. Hope to have some information for you soon.

Comment: @bonehelmet, thanks very much!  I look forward to hearing back from you.

Comment: @bonehelmet any update on this?  This is becoming a real roadblock for us.

Comment: Hi Artie, a bug has been logged and you'll get more traction if you contact Support so they can add you to the number of customer reports associated with it. The reference is W-2487353. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_about

Comment: Thanks @bonehelmet for the update.  I have filed a case to get updates about the issue.