# How to construct a link to the "File Info" page of a File in the SF1 "Files" app?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, chatter-file

I have a VF page that displays a list of Chatter Files.  I use the ConnectAPI in the controller to obtain the ContentCapability object for each file, which in turn provides properties like renditionUrl (link to a preview image), downloadUrl, title, versionId, fileId, etc.

I can display a preview of the file (renditionUrl), link to the "home page" for the file (fileId) and provide download links.  Works well...in the desktop container.

But things break when the VF page is rendered in the SF1 mobile app.  Specifically, the renditionUrl and downloadUrl are broken and this has been acknowledged by SF (see [References to URLs returned by Apex ConnectApi in Salesforce1 mobile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55554/references-to-urls-returned-by-apex-connectapi-in-salesforce1-mobile)).  I worked with support to get a workaround to the renditionUrl issue, but this is the issue that neither I nor support have been able to solve:

**How do I direct the user to a "File Info" page for a File in the SF1 mobile container?**

[image: example "detail" page]
If I could do this, the user could use the native tools to manipulate the file further: download, email, etc.

At one point last fall, I found that constructing a relative url to the file's ID ('/{fileId}') worked in SF1 mobile, but a recent update of SF1 broke it.

I've tried a relative url to the versionID ('/{versionId}') as well, but I can't get it to work.  Similarly, I have been unable to construct a url that acts as a direct download link, despite working with support on things like rewriting the host url from visual.force.com to content.force.com.

So, again, my question is, given the IDs of a (Chatter) file, in the context of a Visualforce page, **how do I direct the user to a "File Info" page for a File in the SF1 mobile container?**

Thanks!

Comment: P.S. If you're wondering, the SF1 "simulator" (/one/one.app using Chrome's mobile tools) displays behavior that is different than either the desktop ("classic") container/UI or the SF1 mobile container, so unfortunately, testing in the simulator doesn't help.